# How do you see what has been edited on an anwser or question?

Tags: discussion, editing

Is there anyway to to see what has been changed in an edit? I know that you can revert the edits if you own the question but it seems as thought there should be a way to see how the anwsers and questions were edited by the mods and others.

Answer (score 1):

[image: How to Edit]

Click this.

Comment: unfortunatly the click this is a box with a red x in it, which makes me think i'm asking a very stupid question

Comment: Uh, I don't understand. Do you see the highlighted part of the image? edited "14 mins ago" Click that, but in an actual question.

Comment: got it now, my work computer was all I had for a while and the image was blocked i guess... thanks for your help